# Can Amphotericin B cross a lipid bilayer membrane in its zwitterionic form when it is loaded in the aqueous core of a liposome?

Tags: physical-chemistry, ph, proteins, lipids

Can Amphotericin B cross a lipid bilayer membrane in its zwitterionic form when it is loaded in the aqueous core of a liposome? Or must it be uncharged in order to cross the lipid bilyer membrane of liposome?

It has a $\textrm{p}K_\textrm{a}$ of 5.7 for the carboxylic acid group and  $\textrm{p}K_\textrm{a}$ of 10  for the $\ce{NH2}$ end and so its pI (pH at the isoelectric point, when it is present as the zwitterionic form) is 7.85.

Comment: Have you tried searching for what makes something able to cross a lipid layer on the internet?

Comment: @TRC yes. it must be uncharged but I don't have an idea that neutral charge zwitterioninc can act like an uncharged drug or not for crossing a lipid bilayer membrane.